# Automatically fill and submit the numbers for website

Tags: javascript

I need to fill table with numbers automatically. And for this cause I'm using this bookmarklet:

```
javascript:var crn=[num1,num2...];
  for(var i=0;i<crn.length;i++){
   var d=document.getElementById("crn_id"+(i+1));
   d.value=crn[i];
}
void(0);
```

It works but I need to click this submit button :

```
<input type="submit" name="REG_BTN" value="Submit Changes">
```

I tried to use this code:

```
javascript: var document.getElementsByTagName('submit')[0].click();
```

There is a sample of the website that I m trying to fill:  (https://web.itu.edu.tr/durgunor/crn.html)
But it doesn't work. How can I fill the table and submit it with unified code?

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByTagName` would have to target a tag (`<input>` in this case). But there might be more inputs and you'd have to know which it is in order (also, the order might change?).

`querySelector` allows targeting by CSS selector. In this case, `name="REG_BTN"`:

```js
document.querySelector('[name=REG_BTN]').click();
```

More on attribute selectors can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Comment: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.' " error pops up

Comment: Try now. I copied your code with initial `javascript: var` which is not needed.